# Citing with En Dash

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Sometimes I need to write a **Newey–West (1987) estimator** rather than **Newey and West's (1987) estimator** as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{z.bib}
@article{newey1987simple,
  title={A Simple, Positive Semi-Definite, Heteroskedasticity and Autocorrelation},
  author={Newey, Whitney K and West, Kenneth D},
  journal={Econometrica},
  volume={55},
  number={3},
  pages={703--708},
  year={1987}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{newey1987simple}'s \citeyearpar{newey1987simple} estimator.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Newey--West (1987) estimator.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliography{z}

\end{document}
```

In this way, can I cite a paper with author names connected via an en dash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your bibliography style supports a customisable name delimiter, then this would be as easy as locally changing this delimiter. Unfortunately, not all `.bst` files support a customisable name delimiter, many just hard-code the "and".

Step 1 is to make `apalike` use a customisable delimiter in citations. To this end

1. Locate `apalike.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich apalike.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `apalike-namedelim.bst`, say (the license of `apalike.bst` requires you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Find `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` (ll. 841-587) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
    FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
    { 's :=
      s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      s num.names$ duplicate$
      #2 >
        { pop$ " et~al." * }
        { #2 <
            'skip$
            { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { "\finalnamedelim " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
   ```
5. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{apalike-namedelim}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/1808df0569958a79ce5058b133495260

Step 2 is to make use of the customisable macro in new commands that we define for the purpose of citing with en-dashes. We just copy the definitions of `\citet` and `\citeauthor` from `natbib.sty` and inject some code to change `\finalnamedelim`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-namedelim}

\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\finalnamedelim}{ and }

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citetattr}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\citetattr
   {\begingroup
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\finalnamedelim}{--}%
    \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
     \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
     
\newcommand*{\citeauthorattr}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\citeauthorattr
   {\begingroup
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\finalnamedelim}{--}%
    \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\@ne\NAT@parfalse
    \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}

\newcommand*{\Citetattr}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Citetattr
   {\begingroup
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\finalnamedelim}{--}%
    \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
     \let\NAT@up\NAT@Up
     \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{newey1987simple,
  title   = {A Simple, Positive Semi-Definite, Heteroskedasticity 
             and Autocorrelation Consistent Covariance Matrix},
  author  = {Newey, Whitney K. and West, Kenneth D.},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  volume  = 55,
  number  = 3,
  pages   = {703--708},
  year    = 1987,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{newey1987simple}'s \citeyearpar{newey1987simple} estimator.

\citetattr{newey1987simple} --- with citation alias

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Newey and West’s (1987) estimator.//Newey–West (1987) — with citation alias]

---

These sort of things are a bit simpler with `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\textattrcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\delimcontext{textattrcite}}}%
  \textcite}

\DeclareDelimFormat[textattrcite]{multinamedelim}{\textendash}
\DeclareDelimAlias[textattrcite]{finalnamedelim}[textattrcite]{multinamedelim}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{newey1987simple,
  title   = {A Simple, Positive Semi-Definite, Heteroskedasticity 
             and Autocorrelation Consistent Covariance Matrix},
  author  = {Newey, Whitney K. and West, Kenneth D.},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  volume  = 55,
  number  = 3,
  pages   = {703--708},
  year    = 1987,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{newey1987simple}'s \parencite*{newey1987simple} estimator.

\textattrcite{newey1987simple} --- with citation alias

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you employ the `natbib` citation management package, you may employ its `\defcitealias` and `\citetalias` macros to achieve your formatting objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{z.bib}
@article{newey1987simple,
  title  ={A Simple, Positive Semi-Definite, Heteroskedasticity 
           and Autocorrelation Consistent Covariance Matrix},
  author ={Newey, Whitney K. and West, Kenneth D.},
  journal={Econometrica},
  volume =55,
  number =3,
  pages  ={703--708},
  year   =1987,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\defcitealias{newey1987simple}{Newey--West (1987)}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\citeauthor{newey1987simple}'s \citeyearpar{newey1987simple} estimator.

\citetalias{newey1987simple} --- with citation alias

Newey--West (1987) --- brute force

\bibliography{z}
\end{document}
```